# Shift a column by a number from another column in the dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame which looks like below:

```
    Sales   Look_back_period
0   100     1
1   102     1
2   103     2
3   108     2
4   100     3
5   90      4
6   97      6

The output I want:
    Sales   Look_back_period    lag_sales
0   100     1                   NaN
1   102     1                   100
2   103     2                   100
3   108     2                   102
4   100     3                   102
5   90      4                   102
6   97      6                   100
```

I want to shift the sales values based on `Look_back_period`.
What I am doing is:

```
df[‘lag_sales’] = df.Sales.shift(df.look_back_period)
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution using a list comprehension with `enumerate`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Look_back_period': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 4, 6: 6},
                             'Sales': {0: 100, 1: 102, 2: 103, 3: 108, 4: 100, 5: 90, 6: 97}})

df['lage_sales'] = [np.nan] + [df['Sales'].iat[i-j] for i, j in \
                               enumerate(df['Look_back_period'].iloc[1:], 1)]

print(df)

   Sales  Look_back_period  lage_sales
0    100                 1         NaN
1    102                 1       100.0
2    103                 2       100.0
3    108                 2       102.0
4    100                 3       102.0
5     90                 4       102.0
6     97                 6       100.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replies but this did not work either. I got the below error:
ValueError: iAt based indexing can only have integer indexers

Comment: @Chirayu05, It certainly works (see update for my input dataframe), just make sure  you copy-paste correctly.

Comment: @Chirayu05, I strongly recommend [EdChum's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704848/edchum) if it works for you, it is vectorised and more stable than mine.

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like a charm now. It did not work for me the 1st time because my column was float64. As soon as i converted it into int64, this worked perfectly well for me :).

Answer (score 6):

Actually you can just `reindex` by subtracting the look_back_period values from the index:

```
In[18]:
df['lag_sales'] = df['Sales'].reindex(df.index - df['Look_back_period']).values
df

Out[18]: 
   Sales  Look_back_period  lag_sales
0    100               NaN        NaN
1    102             100.0      100.0
2    103             100.0      100.0
3    108             102.0      102.0
4    100             102.0      102.0
5     90             102.0      102.0
6     97             100.0      100.0
```

We have to convert to a numpy array using `.values` because without this you will get a `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` error